# “state channel” v.s “micro-payment channel” : are they the same?

Tags: payment, blockchain, ethereum, bitcoin, cryptocurrency

We use "`micro-payment channels`" such as "[Bitcoin Lightning Network](https://dci.mit.edu/lightning-network/)" or "[Duplex Micro-Payment Channels](https://www.tik.ee.ethz.ch/file/716b955c130e6c703fac336ea17b1670/duplex-micropayment-channels.pdf)" for saving transaction fee, accelerating payments, supporting better micro-payment and scaling blockchain.

Is there any difference between "`state channel`" v.s "`micro-payment channe`l"? and if so, what are **differences**?

Answer (score 0):

Micro-payment channel is a subset of state channel. State channels are more general form of payment channels applying the same idea to any kind of state transition systems on Blockchain.

State channels in ethereum supports wider use-cases than payments on bitcoin network.

Good ref: https://www.jeffcoleman.ca/state-channels/